# Chrome - Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am getting below error in chrome for using below

**Error:**

> [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See `url`

**Code:**

```
$('body').on("wheel", "form input[type=number]", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The above code is used for preventing making changes in a number field if the user uses the mouse wheel inside the number input field.

I am getting this error recently, a few days before there were no such errors!!

***Update:**

I have tried adding

```
{
    passive: true
}
```

Like this:

```
$('body').on("wheel", "form input[type=number]", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, {passive: true});
```

Another error is showing:

> ```
> jquery.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: ((r.event.special[g.origType] || {}).handle || g.handler).apply is not a function
>     at HTMLBodyElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
>     at HTMLBodyElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
> ```

How can I fix the error and as well as prevent the mouse wheel inside the number field?

**Chrome Version:** `Chrome 78 on Windows 10`

Comment: Can't reproduce your error. But see some history, try to use: ```{passive:false}``` , like here: ```$('body').on("wheel", "form input[type=number]", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, { passive: true });``` Btw, could you please update the question with Chrome version?

Comment: We need to go deeper. What is the jQuery version?

Comment: jQuery v3.1.1 @Drag13